# How is the weekly income for the junkyard in GTA V calculated?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

The description says the income depends on how many cars are crashed in the game during the week. Does it mean that making cars explode (by shooting at them) will increase my income from the junkyard?

Comment: Based on interpretation alone, I'm going to say yeah, but I dont have a copy to play so I cannot confirm. The BAWSAQ market, from what I have read, is affected by what all players are doing (or by what you are doing, I've read both) in game and thus it goes to say that if you blow up a crap ton of cars then you would see a larger income from the junkyard. (SPECULATION!:)I don't know if they go by weeks in game or weeks in life so I would go on a car destroying spree, blowing up every P.O.S. car on game "Sunday" and not stop til dead or the Sunday to see if that affects the junkyard.

Comment: @ColeBusby - Yes.  You can confirm this.  Blow up 20 cars then wait a week.  After a week blow up 0 cards and wait a week ( just sleep ~14 times ).  Compare the numbers.

Comment: @Ramhound no, I meant I don't have a copy of the game, that comment was speculation, not fact. If you can confirm it, then use the relevant parts of my comment for your answer.

Comment: I find that my fighter jet destroys the cars pretty good; but the salary has never been over $5000. I believe there's a cap income for the junkyard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Car Scrapyard gives you $150 dollars for every car you destroy. You do not need to take the cars to the scrapyard itself.

This is paid out each game week on Monday morning (00:00).

I've just tested this by blowing up two cars on the highway at 23:00 on Sunday. My earnings email for the week came shortly after indicating I'd made $300.

Comment: Do you need to completely destroy the cars, or is enough to crash into them, with a truck?

Comment: The ones I blew up were completely destroyed burnt out husks. I've damaged many cars quite heavily by crashing into them, even taking a wheel off of one and have not been paid for them. The defining factor is most likely whether you can still get into the car or not.

Comment: Confirmed, $150 per car DESTROYED. But seems to have a maximum income of $3900, can anyone else confirm this for me?

Comment: Does it need to be the owner of the scrapyard who destroys the vehicle, or can it be any of the characters who inflicts the destruction?

Comment: I believe it's any of them but I'd have to check to be sure. One thing I have noticed though is that it doesn't seem to pay out for vehicles destroyed on missions. I've come out of very destructive ones expecting a big payout and got nothing.

Comment: It's the owner of the scrap yard that determines the profit.

Answer (score 3):

For every car you destroy you get 150 per week. Mine has capped out at 5000 per week though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Shoot or do whatever you want to a land vehicle until it explodes, and then you get 150 in game dollars at the end of the virtual week. My profits per week seem to stop at $5000 though.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in answers prior to this one and does not add to those answers. As per the [Help Center on what answers are deleted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and the [meta] post, [How do we handle duplicate answers?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4971/4797) - this answer could be deleted.