# Do the destroyed vehicles tallied "roll over" to next week's earnings for the scrapyard in GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I independently confirmed [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131367/how-is-the-weekly-income-for-the-junkyard-in-gta-v-calculated/132345#132345) aswell. I recently bought the scrapyard property and capped out at 5000 from destroying police vehicles; in the SE train tunnel I called the police and continually lured them out only to destroy their vehicles in the tunnel (As bonus the train comes through and does additional damage to vehicles/cops/NOOSE). Once I'm out of ammo I jumped on a train heading north into yet another tunnel, erasing my 5-star wanted level.

**TL;DR Do the weekly earnings roll over? I'm pretty sure after ~4 hours of the above I destroyed more than 33.3 vehicles....**

Also how exactly is a week calculated in GTA V? Is there a way to speed it up? I think sleeping will fast forward you 8 hours but is there any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I destroyed a hideous number of cars as soon as I unlocked the scrap yard but only ever got anywhere near my cap that first week.

You have to destroy your 34 cars each and every week if you want to receive the 5k payout. Destroying 340 cars will not mean you get paid 5k a week for 10 weeks, just the initial 5k.

Safe to say the scrap yard is not going to yield you much income...

Comment: let's focus back on Stock Market. Can't rely on scrap yard for earning